# How to create Bitmap from System.Window.media.PixelFormats.Gray16

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am successfully drawn images from their raw pixel data.(only 8 bit images).
here is the code for doing the same thing.

```
     PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Img_Width, Img_Height, format);
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Img_Width, Img_Height);
     BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, format);
     Marshal.Copy(rawPixel, 0, bmpData.Scan0, rawPixel.Length);
     bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Now as you all know PixelFormat.format16bppGrayscale is not supported by c# 2.0 GDI+.
I googled and got 3.0/3.5 framework support this.
So i installed both.
The class which is support is System.windows.media.PixelFormats.
PixelFormats.Gray16

Now my problem is how to create a bitmap and get a image for display by passing this parameter.

i got something BitmapSource class there but i am very new in C#3.0.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static Bitmap changePixelFormat(Bitmap input, PixelFormat format)
{
    Bitmap retval=new Bitmap(input.Width, input.Height, format);
    retval.SetResolution(input.HorizontalResolution, input.VerticalResolution);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(retval);
    g.DrawImage(input, 0, 0);
    g.Dispose();
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: I admit this is not precisely what you are asking for, but it should either work as an alternative or be adjustable by creating a new input bitmap and copying the raw data onto it so that you'll have something to pass into changePixelFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Greyscale filters](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f0c2a0fb-12a4-0ab4-81cd-095f482b1383.htm) in [AForge.net](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/).  You can find source [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx?fid=158880&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=201).

EDIT:

As a note on that source I linked, it is using an 'old' version of AForge.NET, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: thanks Jason,
I tried that code earlier but image display is not proper.
I will tell you it can work if you pass 16bppRGB555 but image looks in color.
But you cannot pass 16bppGrayscale.so not correct display.